# Not able to install ibm security and compliance 4.0.0 version. By default 3.0.0 gets installed

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm tring to install IBM Security and Compliance Center 4.0.0 by the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade "ibm-scc>=4.0.0"
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> ibm-scc>=4.0.0 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4, 0.0.7,
> 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.0.10, 0.0.13, 0.0.14, 0.0.15, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.0.0, 3.0.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for ibm-scc>=4.0.0

Comment: Where did you find info about 4.0.0 version? If you look at the https://pypi.org/project/ibm-scc/ the latest version is 3.0.0.